# DV6325us and AR9002wb-1ng

Tags: 11.04, wireless, bluetooth

I have recently added an Atheros AR9002wb-1ng WiFi combo card to my HP Pavilion Dv6325us laptop. I had to modify my BIOS to get the WiFi to work, but the Bluetooth isn't working. It's not even detected.

*** LSPCI ***

```
00:00.0 RAM memory: nVidia Corporation C51 Host Bridge (rev a2)
00:00.1 RAM memory: nVidia Corporation C51 Memory Controller 0 (rev a2)
00:00.2 RAM memory: nVidia Corporation C51 Memory Controller 1 (rev a2)
00:00.3 RAM memory: nVidia Corporation C51 Memory Controller 5 (rev a2)
00:00.4 RAM memory: nVidia Corporation C51 Memory Controller 4 (rev a2)
00:00.5 RAM memory: nVidia Corporation C51 Host Bridge (rev a2)
00:00.6 RAM memory: nVidia Corporation C51 Memory Controller 3 (rev a2)
00:00.7 RAM memory: nVidia Corporation C51 Memory Controller 2 (rev a2)
00:02.0 PCI bridge: nVidia Corporation C51 PCI Express Bridge (rev a1)
00:03.0 PCI bridge: nVidia Corporation C51 PCI Express Bridge (rev a1)
00:05.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation C51 [Geforce Go 6150] (rev a2)
00:09.0 RAM memory: nVidia Corporation MCP51 Host Bridge (rev a2)
00:0a.0 ISA bridge: nVidia Corporation MCP51 LPC Bridge (rev a3)
00:0a.1 SMBus: nVidia Corporation MCP51 SMBus (rev a3)
00:0a.3 Co-processor: nVidia Corporation MCP51 PMU (rev a3)
00:0b.0 USB Controller: nVidia Corporation MCP51 USB Controller (rev a3)
00:0b.1 USB Controller: nVidia Corporation MCP51 USB Controller (rev a3)
00:0d.0 IDE interface: nVidia Corporation MCP51 IDE (rev f1)
00:0e.0 IDE interface: nVidia Corporation MCP51 Serial ATA Controller (rev f1)
00:10.0 PCI bridge: nVidia Corporation MCP51 PCI Bridge (rev a2)
00:10.1 Audio device: nVidia Corporation MCP51 High Definition Audio (rev a2)
00:14.0 Bridge: nVidia Corporation MCP51 Ethernet Controller (rev a3)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] HyperTransport Technology Configuration
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] Address Map
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] DRAM Controller
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] Miscellaneous Control
03:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
07:05.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Ricoh Co Ltd R5C832 IEEE 1394 Controller
07:05.1 SD Host controller: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C822 SD/SDIO/MMC/MS/MSPro Host Adapter (rev 19)
07:05.2 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C592 Memory Stick Bus Host Adapter (rev 0a)
07:05.3 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd xD-Picture Card Controller (rev 05)
```

*** LSUSB ***

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0557:2220 ATEN International Co., Ltd
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

*** LSHW ***

```
*-pci:1
   description: PCI bridge
   product: C51 PCI Express Bridge
   vendor: nVidia Corporation
   physical id: 3
   bus info: pci@0000:00:03.0
   version: a1
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pci pm msi ht pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=pcieport
   resources: irq:41 memory:b6000000-b7ffffff
   *-network
      description: Wireless interface
      product: AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
      vendor: Atheros Communications Inc.
      physical id: 0
      bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
      logical name: wlan1
      version: 01
      serial: e0:b9:a5:9b:c3:65
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 33MHz
      capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical 
wireless
      configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=2.6.38-8-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
      resources: irq:19 memory:b6000000-b600ffff
```

Comment: There is nothing that I can see that says bluetooth is either visible or hardware-enabled.  Check if there is a harware-switch to enable, or if there is some bios value available.  On some laptops there is a FN+<key>  to enable bluetooth.

Comment: Here's the thing, when I install the module into a friends notebook, the blue-tooth is detected. It seems that it is only undetectable in my notebook.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [How to report a bug](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug). Regards,

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not found a solution and I am going to assume that this is a hardware problem.